# The Determinant of a Matrix Is the Product of Its Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Prove that determinant of a matrix $A$ is the product of its eigenvalues (counting multiplicities).

We are given the following hint: first, show that $\det(A - x I) = (\lambda_1 - x)(\lambda_2 - x) \cdots (\lambda_n - x),$ where the $\lambda_i$ are (not necessarily distinct) eigenvalues of $A;$ then, compare the free terms (i.e., the terms without $x$), or plug in $x = 0$ to get the conclusion.

Comment: What have you attempted for the problem? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: expanding the det(A-I) I got (a11-)(a22-)...(ann-)+p() but don't really know where to go from there. @Carlo

Comment: That is very bad. Recall that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $\det(A - xI)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n.$ Can you use this to finish the problem? (I imagine from this that you can assume that $A$ has entries in some algebraically closed field -- probably the complex numbers $\mathbb C.$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{K}) $ such that $\mathbb{K} =\overline{\mathbb{K} } $ then
let
$|A-\lambda id| =\Pi_{i=1}^n{(\lambda_i-\lambda) }$ counting multiplicity of $\lambda_i$, so now
Since $|A|$=$|A-\lambda id|$ with $\lambda=0$ and remplazing
$\lambda=0$
$|A|=\Pi_{i=1}^n{\lambda_i} $
$\square$